# What is version of FOP used in Oracle Application Express APEX 5

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, xsl-fo, apache-fop, oracle-apex-5

Which version of XSL-FO specification is used in ORDS(Oracle Restful Data Services) which is the new APEX Listener in APEX version 5.x?

Thanks!

P.S. XSL-FO specification 1.0 was used in Apex Listener of Oracle Application Express (APEX) 4.2.

Comment: No need for BI publisher or FOP to print PDF's from Apex 5.0.

https://chefdba.com/tag/pdf-printing-in-apex-5/

Comment: I don't think you have understood my question. I would like to know which version of XSL-FO specification is used in ORDS(Oracle Restful Data Services) which is the new APEX Listener in APEX version 5.x

Comment: Format a PDF, open it and look at the Producer properties

Comment: @KevinBrown, Thanks! I found the specs, it uses Apache FOP 1.0. I can now disregard elements/attributes introduced in versions > 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APEX 5 ORDS uses Apache FOP Release 1.0 print formatter. This release implements a good subset of the W3C XSL-FO 1.0 and 1.1 Standards. For more detailed overview, visit the [compliance page](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html).